# CREAR TABLA DESDE UNA CONSULTA SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server

Quisiera armar una consulta que me devuelta la fila de DESC_CORT_FTO como columna como muesta la siguiente imagen [image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

---

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Quisiera que me de el resultado de la siguiente manera, ya que lo hize con javascript pero en las columnas de division se me complica por eso obte por realizar una consulta sql

Comment: Lo que pides es un pivotado. Pero es algo que al menos en mi criterio, requiere tener bien claro, lo que quieres mostrar. No basta con decir que la columna se muestre como fila. Sino establecer si los valores R.O, R.D.R, DNE Y R.D son únicos, o realmente puede haber infinitos más. Plantea un buen escenario, porque sino, las respuestas no van a ser eficaces para tí. Ni tampoco aportarán nada a quienes te quieren ayudar. [mcve].

Comment: Los campos RO RDR DNE RD son unicos, pero quisiera obtener el total de registros por mes de cada uno de ellos, tienes razon creo que es pivot la logica que podria usar, pero mi resultado quisiera que salga de esta manera.

Answer (score 0):

El escenario que has puesto, es muy escaso, pero como por algún motivo, ha desparecido la imágen del resultado que pusiste, he decido responder de igual manera.

```
Create table sourceTable
(codi_fuen_fto varchar(4), desc_cort_fto varchar(10), mes varchar(15), Total int)
Insert into sourceTable(codi_fuen_fto, desc_cort_fto, mes, Total)
values
('0001','R.O', 'FEBRERO',2),
('0002','R.D.R.', 'FEBRERO',1),
('0003','DNE', 'ENERO',0),
('0005','R.D', 'ENERO',0);
```

En vez de trabajar con la consulta, dado que no tengo un escenario con datos, y para el caso del pivot no me hace falta, directamente cargo los valores que has puesto en una tabla.

He cambiado, que las filas '0003' y '000t', tienen un mes, sobre todo porque se vea el sentido del pivot.

```
SELECT * FROM
(
-- AQUÍ TU CONSULTA
    SELECT T.desc_cort_fto, 
           T.MES,
           T.Total
        FROM sourceTable T
-- FIN DE LA CONSULTA
) AS SOURCE
PIVOT (SUM(TOTAL) FOR desc_cort_fto 
IN ([R.O], [R.D.R.],[DNE],[R.D]))pvt
```

[image: Res1]

En la tabla derivada donde he puesto el aquí tú consulta, observarás que he quitado la columna `codi_fuen_fto`, puesto que no aporta valor, y no permite agrupar una suma de resultados por mes.

Lo que hace la query es sumar lo que contenga total para cada una de las descripciones mencionadas en In.

Esto es lo que se conoce como un pivot estático. Porque solo sirve para esos valores que se han puesto entre corchetes.

Si la solución no es lo que esperas, tendrás que mejorar y mucho el escenario.

[Pivot simple. ¿Cómo hacerlo y entenderlo paso a paso?](https://javifer2.wordpress.com/2019/10/16/pivot-simple-como-hacer-y-entenderlo-paso-por-paso/)

[Pivot dinámico. ¿Cómo hacerlo y entenderlo paso a paso?](https://javifer2.wordpress.com/2019/11/14/pivot-dinamico-como-hacerlo-y-entenderlo/)